# C++ inherit template class: hidden member variable

Tags: c++

Why is the following code not compiling?

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class A
{
  public:
  T data;
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
 public:
 void foo(){printf("%d\n", data);}
};

int main() 
{
  B<int> b;
}
```

Error:

```
bla.cpp: In member function ‘void B<T>::foo()’:
bla.cpp:14:30: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
void foo(){printf("%d\n", data);}
```

It seems that the member variable "data" is hidden for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the base's member variables via `this`:

```
this->data;
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem, but this feels very odd. I wouldn't have to do this if A and B would not be template classes. Why is this?